# CopyTo Paste Values on Google script pastes blanks

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, copy, paste

Below is code that works perfectly until the last line where i try to copy and paste values on the same range.  The formula pulls the correct information, but when the copy paste values is run, all the cells become blank. NOTE: the first cell in the range would calculate as blank.  Please let me know where I've gone wrong!

```
function CopyTo() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var evnt = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell();
  var rw = evnt.getRow();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Calendar'), true);

  var rng = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rw,12,1,365);
  rng.setFormulaR1C1('=iferror(index(CPS,match(RC2,CPRows,0),match((column()-match(RC4,Dateslist,0)-11),CPCol,0)),"")\n');
  rng.copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rw,12,1,365), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

 };
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You might try putting a SpreadsheetApp.flush() between the last two lines.

Comment: Can you please share a sanitised copy of your Sheet? Or an example sheet which this can be reproduced with?

Comment: Thanks Copper, but unfortunately, that didn't work.  Rafa, i'll see if i can recreate it on a sanitised copy.  Thanks

Comment: Was this every solved?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Like Cooper says, try putting this line before the last line:

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

But then also pull the ranges again in the last line and don't use the variables you previously created. Like this:

```
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rw,12,1,365).copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getRange(rw,12,1,365), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
```